# ZIP password cracker being able to deal with more recent versions of ZIP format

Tags: open-source, zip, password-recovery

I am looking for a ZIP password cracking tool that is capable of dealing with modern variants of the ZIP format.

When I opened it it shows errors about requiring "PK compat. v5.1". Tools like John the Ripper jumbo (`zip2john`) also fail, some claim the file isn't protected. 7-Zip seems to be able to detect it as password-protected, but doesn't help in cracking/recovering the password.

It's a ZIP file alright, even according to `file` (i.e. libmagic), but I have yet to come by a tool that is able to detect it as password-protected *and* to allow me to brute-force the password.

Open source solutions preferred.